# How can I run 2 methods simultaneosly

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to play a song on 2 buzzers using my arduino mega 25600, but I suck at C++. I have managed to figure out how to play on one buzzer, but I want to play 2 different melodies simultaneously on 2 different buzzers. Here is my code:

```
#include "piezo-music.h"


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  int melody1[] = {
    NOTE_FS4, NOTE_CS5, NOTE_AS4, NOTE_AS4, 
    NOTE_GS4, NOTE_FS4, NOTE_FS4, NOTE_B4, 
    NOTE_AS4, NOTE_AS4, NOTE_GS4, NOTE_GS4, 
    NOTE_FS4, NOTE_FS4, NOTE_CS5, NOTE_AS4, 
    NOTE_AS4, NOTE_GS4, NOTE_GS4, NOTE_FS4, 
    NOTE_FS4, NOTE_DS4, NOTE_CS4, PAUSE
  };
  int rythm1[] = {
    4, 8, 8, 4, 8, 8, 8, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 3, 2
  };
  int size = sizeof(melody1) / sizeof(int); // Get the length of your array/melody
  playSong(11, melody1, rythm1, size, 45);


}
```

For the line that says `playSong(11, melody1, rythm1, size, 45);`, 11 is the anode pin on the arduino giving off the specific frequencies, melody1 was the int array for the frequencies, rythm1 was the int array for the duration of the notes, and 45 is the tempo in beats per minute.

The library just defines the notes as frequencies, but you can find it here: https://github.com/PeCeSe/Arduino-piezo-music

I guess what I want to do is run two "playSong()" lines simultaneously, but I could only think of having 2 methods having the code and them being simultaneously called in void loop(). And I've already tried putting a playSong() right after the first playsong() and it just plays it after the first one plays.

I researched a bit but couldn't find my answer. Although I found tasks and threads, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what exactly they do.

Comment: Your code seems C++. Are you sure you writing C# code ?

Comment: The code is definitely not C# but in C# one would use Tasks

Comment: my bad, it is C++.

Comment: The Arduino is a microcontroller and is therefore not multi-tasking or multi-threaded, so your options are limited. One idea would be to move to an ESP32 which is dual core and runs a multi-tasking OS. The other would be to find the shortest note in your two melodies and then play everything as a multiple of that on both buzzers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: you can't use piezo-music.h to play two tones at once. You can't even play two tones at once using Arduino's tone() and noTone() functions. ...but there does seem to be an Arduino library that lets you play multiple tones simultaneously.

The details:

https://github.com/PeCeSe/Arduino-piezo-music/blob/master/piezo-music.h - the piezo-music.h library - creates music using the tone(), noTone(), and delay() Arduino functions. The tone() function reference, at https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/, says "Only one tone can be generated at a time".

The details are briefly described at https://github.com/bhagman/Tone#ugly-details. That page says that the tone() and noTone() functions use one Arduino timer to generate a tone, and that if you're using an Arduino that has multiple available timers, you should be able to write low-level timer code to produce multiple simultaneous tones on different pins.

Digging around the net, I found a library that lets you use multiple Tone objects - and multiple hardware timers - to play multiple tones simultaneously. The 2011 note about using it is at https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=77447.msg586674#msg586674

That Tone library, that plays multiple tones simultaneously, is at https://github.com/bhagman/Tone - NOTE: I haven't tried it out.

Good luck, and post what you find!

Comment: Thanks it worked. Although it was very complex to set it up, but i got the same melody play on 2 buzzers simultaneously. Thanks again for your time and effort.